# Passing many arguments to the constructor in python

Tags: python, typeerror

I am trying to pass many arguments to a constructor but when i try to call a method; i have an error. I did instantiate my class; but i get an error. What i have is for example in my main function is:

```
Points = Line(1,1,2,3)
a= Line.slope() 
print("slope",a)
```

in my class i have

```
class Line(object):
   def __init__(self,X1,Y1,X2,Y2):
      self.k1=X1
      self.k2=Y1   
      self.k3=X2
      self.k4=Y2 

''' Compute the slope of the line'''
   def slope(self):

        x1, y1, x2, y2 = self.k1, self.k2, self.k3, self.k4
        try:
                return (float(y2)-y1)/(float(x2)-x1)
        except ZeroDivisionError:
                # line is vertical
                return None
'''Get the y intercept of a line segment'''
    def yintercept(self, slope):

        if slope != None:
                x, y = self.k1, self.k2
                return y - self.slope * x
        else:
                return None
'''Find Y cord using line equation'''
   def solve_for_y(self, x, slope, yintercept):

        if slope != None and yintercept != None:
                return float(slope) * x + float(yintercept)
        else:
                raise Exception("impossible to get it")
'''Find X cord using line equation'''
   def solve_for_x(self, y, slope, yintercept):

        if slope != 0 and slope:
                return float((y - float(yintercept))) / float(slope)
        else:
                raise Exception("Imposssible to get it ")
```

The error is have is: TypeError: Compute missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'.

I am not what the problem is.

That is my complete code

Comment: Perhaps you can post your actual code. What you've posted has a number of typos that would produce other error messages besides the one you're showing us.

Comment: is `Compute` a method in your class? can you fix indentation to better see what your intentions are?

Answer (score 3):

You've got a few issues with your existing class.

```
class TestClass():
    def __init__(self,x1,x2,x3):
        self.k1 = x1
        self.k2 = x2
        self.k3 = x3

    def Compute(self):
        return self.k1 * self.k2 + self.k3

>>> test = TestClass(2,2,3)
>>> test.Compute()
7
```

- The method `_init_` should be `__init__` (note the double underscores)
- Your `Compute` method should use the member variables `k` instead of the input variables `x` because the x versions don't exist in that scope
- Your capitalization of `Compute` was incorrect when you called the method.
- You are missing a `:` after your `class` declaration and the `__init__` function definition

Comment: I did exactly the same as you did but i still have the same error

Comment: Then you did something incorrectly, because as I showed you after the class definition, I tested the function and the output seems correct to me.